# Make Cordova use old CordovaWebView instead of SystemWebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview, calabash

I'm using cordova with Ionic and calabash-android for automated tests. In old projects Cordova was using org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView as webview. This is what calabash-android supports. In newer project Cordova uses org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView as webview which confuse Calabash. Is there a way to switch a newer project to the old webview? I only need this until calabash for Android has catched up.

Old projects which where the platform was added before the change do stil use CordovaWebView so it feels like this should be possible but I haven't find a way to do it.

Cheers
Pascal

Comment: Unless you install the crosswalk plugin, the webview is still a CordovaWebView, systemWebview will return the CordovaWebView if you use it's getCordovaWebView() method

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest pre-release (0.5.13.pre1) handles this:

-https://rubygems.org/gems/calabash-android/versions/0.5.13.pre1